# Ruby on Rails 3.1- JSON API implementation

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am implementing a JSON API using ruby on rails 3.1. Which tools/gems/plugings should I use OR simply implement it using rails standard .json response format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gowallas [Boxer](https://github.com/gowalla/boxer) will come in handy I guess